# Cast an object to a certain type based on a string

Tags: c#, casting

I have a 'basetype' object that I wish to cast to a specific type. I want to make this generic, so I wish to get the name of the object and cast it to a class with the same name. Something like so :

```
string name = baseObj.name;

var baseObj = baseObj as getClassFor(name);
```

I have found the Activator but I Activator.CreateInstance(), i dont think, is what I need.

My question is, how do I cast an object to a certain type based on a string?

Comment: Why you need that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter as we have a bunch of objects to check the type of and cast to that type, so rather than doing a lot of if elses, or switch statements, I thought it would be possible to do it in a couple of lines

Comment: try to use generics instead of string name

Comment: @Rudresh could you give me an example, ill do some research myself now

Comment: @thatOneGuy: i still don't understand why you have a "bunch of objects to check the type and cast to that type". Why the caller doesn't know what type of object it is? Insted of strings use the type (generics). Why you need to cast at all? It seems you put everything in a `List<BaseType>` and then you want to take out the actualy type later. You can use `list.OfType<SpecificType>()` to get only the objects which are of your desired type.

Answer (score 1):

As casting is mostly a compile time thing, you can't cast to a specific Type based on a string, so you have to use the `dynamic` keyword.

```
var t= Type.GetType(baseObj.name); //This should contain the correct namespace too. ex. "MyNamespace.SpecificClass"
dynamic specificObj = Convert.ChangeType(baseObj, t);
specificObj.SpecificMethod();
```